# Strange/unexpected jQuery promise reject behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am experimenting some strange behaviours with jQuery promises on reject.
I have an array of promises, and I need to work with them when they all have been resolved/rejected.

To do so, I am using this:

```
var array_res = [];
array_res.push(promiseResolve('a'));
array_res.push(promiseReject('b'));

$.when.apply(null,array_res).always( function ( ) {
  console.log(arguments);
  //Work to do
} );

function promiseResolve (c) {
  var promise = $.Deferred();
  promise.resolve({a:c});
  return promise;
}

function promiseReject (c) {
  var promise = $.Deferred();
  promise.reject({b:c});
  return promise;
}
```

The issue is:

If I resolve both promises, everything works fine.

If I reject one of the promises, then the arguments come incomplete.

If I reject both of them, then the arguments come incomplete.

Here are 3 fiddles where you can check the behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/daepqzv1/1/

https://jsfiddle.net/daepqzv1/2/

https://jsfiddle.net/daepqzv1/3/

What I need is a way to get the arguments for both, rejected and resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131082/jquery-ajax-prevent-fail-in-a-deferred-sequential-loop

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042068/why-is-onrejected-not-called-following-promise-all-where-promise-reject-incl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior for `$.when()`.  If any promises you pass to `$.when()` reject, then `$.when()` will reject with the first reject reason that it finds.  This is how it is coded.

This is similar to the way the ES6 `Promise.all()` works.

If you want all results, even if some promises reject, then you can use something like `$.settle()` or `$.settleVal()` that are defined in this code:

```
(function() {    

    function isPromise(p) {
        return p && (typeof p === "object" || typeof p === "function") && typeof p.then === "function";
    }

    function wrapInPromise(p) {
        if (!isPromise(p)) {
            p = $.Deferred().resolve(p);
        }
        return p;
    }

    function PromiseInspection(fulfilled, val) {
        return {
            isFulfilled: function() {
                return fulfilled;
            }, isRejected: function() {
                return !fulfilled;
            }, isPending: function() {
                // PromiseInspection objects created here are never pending
                return false;
            }, value: function() {
                if (!fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .value() on a promise that is not fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }, reason: function() {
                if (fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .reason() on a promise that is fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }
        };
    }

    // pass either multiple promises as separate arguments or an array of promises
    $.settle = function(p1) {
        var args;
        if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
              args = p1;
        } else {
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        }

        return $.when.apply($, args.map(function(p) {
            // make sure p is a promise (it could be just a value)
            p = wrapInPromise(p);
            // Now we know for sure that p is a promise
            // Make sure that the returned promise here is always resolved with a PromiseInspection object, never rejected
            return p.then(function(val) {
                return new PromiseInspection(true, val);
            }, function(reason) {
                // convert rejected promise into resolved promise by returning a resolved promised
                // One could just return the promiseInspection object directly if jQuery was
                // Promise spec compliant, but jQuery 1.x and 2.x are not so we have to take this extra step
                return wrapInPromise(new PromiseInspection(false, reason));
            });
        })).then(function() {
              // return an array of results which is just more convenient to work with
              // than the separate arguments that $.when() would normally return
            return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        });
    }

    // simpler version that just converts any failed promises
    // to a resolved value of what is passed in, so the caller can just skip
    // any of those values in the returned values array
    // Typically, the caller would pass in null or 0 or an empty object
    $.settleVal = function(errorVal, p1) {
        var args;
        if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
              args = p1;
        } else {
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        }
        return $.when.apply($, args.map(function(p) {
            p = wrapInPromise(p);
            return p.then(null, function(err) {
                return wrapInPromise(errorVal);
            });
        }));
    }
})();
```

`$.settle()` always resolves and it resolves with an array of `PromiseInspection` objects that you can then iterate over to see which promises resolved and which rejected and what the value or reason was.

`$.settleVal()` is a little simpler to iterate, but a little less generic because it doesn't give you the reject reason.  It always resolves with an array where a reject will have a default value that you pass to it in the array in place of the resolved value.

FYI, both `$.settle()` and `$.settleVal()` can both be passed an array of promises like `$.settle(arrayOfPromises)` or multiple promise arguments as `$.settle(p1, p2, p3)` (as `$.when()` works).  This saves having to use `.apply()` when you have an array of promises.

Comment: So there is no way in hell I can get arguments for all the promises?

Comment: Took me some time to adapt it, but seems to be working! thank you very much! :)