# Can we get current promise in then?

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, promise

I want to have some mechanism to redo then function in promise. Keep doing it until it pass some check

```
somePromise.then(() => {
    if(state == "finish")
        return;

    // DoSomething async then repeat these codes
    // could we do it by [return this;] ?
}).then(() => console.log("finish"));
```

Comment: `var retry = fn => _ => fn().catch(retry(fn));` - and have fn throw if check failed ... usage: `retry(fn).then(ok => console.log(ok));`

Comment: Wait so do you want to re-run `somePromise.then(() => {` IF some condition inside the first `.then` is satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the function used at `.then()`, recursively call same function at `.then()` of `doSomethingAsync()` call until `state == "finish"`

```
// name function used at `.then()` 
somePromise.then(function re(data) {
    if(state == "finish") {
        return data;
    };
    // DoSomething async then repeat these codes
    // call `re` at `.then()` chained to `doSomethingAsync()`
    doSomethinAsync(data).then(re);
}).then((data) => console.log("finish", data));
```

See also [multiple, sequential fetch() Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034574/multiple-sequential-fetch-promise/)

Comment: Thanks. I was using lambda as callback too much till I forgot that we can name callback. This is neat

Answer (score 3):

In general, you don't get access to the current promise inside the `.then()` handler.  And, for the most part, you couldn't do anything useful anyway.  Adding another `.then()` handler does not do anything different than the `.then()` handler you're already in.  Once fulfilled, promises never change their state.

If you want to repeat something, you make a function out of the thing you want to repeat and you call it over again from within the `.then()` handler and you return the resulting promise (thus chaining it to the previous promise).

Here's an example:

```
// utility delay function that returns a promise
function delay(t, val) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           resolve(val);
       }, t);
   });
}

// repeatedly call someAsyncOp() until we see the operation is finished
function repeatUntil(t) {
   return someAsyncOp().then(function(state) {
      if (state !== "finish") {
           return delay(t).then(repeatUntil);
      }
   });
} 

// sample usage
repeatUntil(5000).then(function() {
    // state is finished here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```