# Waiting for Recursive Function To Complete

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I have a recursive Javascript function which gets the links from one Wikipedia page, follows them, and then gets all of those links (repeating a specified number of times).

It calls itself an unknown number of times to construct an object of a known depth. When it completes, I want to output the object. Currently the object immediately outputs, and is empty, meaning the function obviously isn't waiting for all the recursive calls to complete.

As you can see, I have attempted to use callbacks, but I assume incorrectly. What am I doing wrong, how should I be doing it? I'm going to presume there's a few other things wrong I haven't spotted too; I'm relatively new to Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  pageLinks[START_PAGE] = {};
  //Get initial pages
  links = getLinks(START_PAGE, 0, printLinks));
});

function printLinks()
{
  console.log(links);
}

function getLinks(currentPage, level, callback)
{
  visitedPages.push(currentPage)
  var pageLinks = {}
  var data = $.getJSON(URL_BEGIN + currentPage + URL_END, function(data)
  {
    var pages = data.query.pages;
    for(var page in pages)
    {
      pageContentObj = pages[page].revisions[0];
      for(var key in pageContentObj) if(pageContentObj[key].length > 100)
      {
        var pageContent = pageContentObj[key];
        //Get links
        hyperlinks = getFromBetween.get(pageContent,"[[","]]");
        for(var link in hyperlinks)
        {
          link = hyperlinks[link].split("|")[0]; //Remove friendly name
          link = link.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

          //Add to pagelist object
          prefix = link.split(":")[0];
          if(prefix != "Category" && prefix != "File" && prefix != "wikipedia")
            if(level < ITERATIONS && !visitedPages.includes(arguments, link))
            {
              console.log(level + ": " + link)
              pageLinks[link] = getLinks(link, level+1, callback); //===Recursive call===
            }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  if(level == 0 && callback) callback();
  return pageLinks;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

**EDIT: ** Link: https://github.com/JakeStanger/Wikipedia-Mapper/blob/master/init.js#L53

Comment: This has the very real possibility of sucking wikipedia down to your server. Are you sure you want to do this to your server and allowed to do this by Wikipedia?

Comment: Substitute `Promise.all()`, `Array.prototype.map()` for `for..in` loops. See also [multiple, sequential fetch() Promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034574/multiple-sequential-fetch-promise)

Comment: I'm only running it on my home pc as a bit of an experiment, so max 38Mb/s - I've tested it a few times and Wikipedia seems to hold up fine...

Comment: So you are planning to print it out? https://img.labnol.org/di/wikipedia-print.jpg

Comment: @mplungjan https://what-if.xkcd.com/59/

Comment: @Jonasw: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Size_in_volumes

Answer (score 2):

The recursive call needs to be like this:

```
var counter = 0;
//the big for loop
counter++;
getLinks(link, level + 1, function(res) {
    for (var key in res) { //with an array it would be concat...
        pageLinks[key] = res[key];
    }
    counter--;
    if (counter == 0 && callback) callback(pageLinks); //callback if all callbacks called
});
```

Also remove this weird code:

```
if(level == 0 && callback) callback();
```

No you can do:

```
getLinks(START_PAGE, 0, console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm getting no outputted object now though. Above have you purposely used `key` to refer to the existing variable or should this be renamed?

Comment: @JakeStanger key is defined in the for in loop. if theres another var called key you should rename one of them...

Comment: Figured that was the case. I'm still getting no output though. Lemme upload it to Github and I'll edit my original post with a link...

Comment: @JakeStanger ok. but i will leave SO for a while, may react tomorrow

Comment: It's fine, I'm in no hurry. This is only a little experiment in my spare time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I still can't get this to work, would you mind looking at my linked code and helping out? Thanks.

Comment: @JakeStanger oh sorry, ive forgot you. And no i cannot help you without a specific error. Debug debug debug.