# jquery ajax inside loop return statusText error, Status 0 after certain time in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I m trying to update bulk of data one by one using Jquery ajax,so that i can show update progress. every thing goes well at beginning but after 5 min, it throw an error like in 
Image while checking network request/respond:.

[image: network error]

Error on error function of ajax:.

[image]

MainData is array of json object and is contain around 3000 number of json object.

```
function DoPost()
   {
       $.each(MainData, function (key, value) {
          var mainCode = value.MainCode;
          var companyCode = value.CompanyCode;
          $.ajax({
              url: "Allotment.asmx/DoAllotment",
              data: "{MainCode:'" + mainCode + "', sNoOfAllotment:'" + noOfAllot + "',CompanyCode:'" + companyCode + "'}",
              dataType: 'text',
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              type: "Post",
              success: function (res){
                   Progress(res);   // this funtion will show progress of update.
               },
               error: function (res) {
                   console.log(res);
               }
           });
       });
    }
```

I am using web service of asp.net webform

Comment: Please add images in the question as you mentioned.

Comment: sorry bro i didn't have enough reputation to add image. so image was not displayed. now it is on..plz check now

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be maximum number of concurrent connections to same URL. You can schedule next `$.ajax()` call when current `$.ajax()` completes.

See also [multiple, sequential fetch() Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034574/multiple-sequential-fetch-promise/)

```
function DoPost(value) {
  var mainCode = value.MainCode;
  var companyCode = value.CompanyCode;
  return $.ajax({
    url: "Allotment.asmx/DoAllotment",
    data: "{MainCode:'" + mainCode + "', sNoOfAllotment:'" 
           + noOfAllot + "',CompanyCode:'" + companyCode + "'}",
    dataType: 'text',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(res) {
      Progress(res); // this funtion will show progress of update.
    },
    error: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
}

var copy = MainData.slice(0);
var res = (function re(value) {
  return DoPost(value).then(function() {
    return copy.length ? re(copy.shift()) : "complete"
  })
})(copy.shift());

res.then(function(complete) {
  console.log(complete)
}, function(err, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

Comment: Promises in javascript is totally new for me. Sir could you please explain a bit more, how this code works.

Comment: The pattern creates a copy of the original array, in case original array needs to be preserved at `copy`, then calls `$.ajax()` request in sequential order, making next request when previous request completes. You could alternatively post `MainData` at one `POST` request, given explanation of issue by @TariqB.

Answer (score 0):

The error `0x2ee2` is IE's representation of timeout error. The occurrence of this error shows that the server has stopped responding to the requests due to a high number of requests sent from the same client. This is the **server avoiding DOS attacks** from the client.

The proper method is to optimize the code and try to utilize the maximum available bandwidth in order to minimize the number of requests to the server.